# Get image propotions residing in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I've got multiple svgs inside multiple divs.

```
<div id="divA">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    
     <rect x="10" y="10" height="130" width="500" style="fill: #000000"/>

     <image class="myImg" x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80"
     xlink:href="img.png" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

I'm looking a way access the image width and height inside divA. How can I get the width and height of `img.png` assigned to variables?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#divA svg image').getAttribute('height')`?

Comment: @Vohuman thanks. Very good . Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
var divA = document.getElementById("divA");
var imageInsideDivA = divA.getElementsByTagName("image")[0];

// Get Width
var width = imageInsideDivA.getAttribute("width");
// Get Height
var height = imageInsideDivA.getAttribute("height");
// Get value of xlink:href
var xlinkHref = imageInsideDivA.getAttribute("xlink:href");
```

Comment: @Becky I have added another line to the answer code, to get the xlink:href value.